# Why is this a Poisson approximation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

The problem is as follows:
Customers arrive at a checkout counter randomly, at a rate of 10 per hour. What is the best approximation of the number of customers that arrive at the checkout counter in 30 minutes?

I'm not sure why we should use Poisson to approximate it? Why not normal distribution?

Comment: Here's one way to look at it. Divide the 30 minute time period into one second intervals. Define $X_i$ to be $1$ if a customer arrives during the $i$ time interval, and $0$ otherwise. Assuming that customers never arrive within one second of each other, the number of customers that arrive during the 30 minute time period is $X = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$, where $n$ is the number of seconds in 30 minutes. We can make a modeling assumption that the random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent. Under this assumption, $X$ is a binomial random variable and the Poisson approximation applies.

Comment: The normal distribution is a continuous distribution. It can be used to approximate a discrete distribution in certain cases, but here the number of customers arriving is among the integers $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$ and clearly it is improbable that the number will be large: the expected number is only $5.$ How could it make sense to use a normal distribution?